# android shared preference one key with multiple values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My query is straight forward, couldn't find answer across google:

For Example:

Repository 1  -> username1
              -> password1

Repository 2  -> username2
              -> password2

Repository 3  -> username3
              -> password3

As mentioned above, I have a dialog box with three repositories. When user selects a repository automatically another dialog box pops up to enter username and password.

So, what i am trying to achieve is to save repository name, username and password in a shared preference with a single key.

I know how to create a shared pref object with a single key and value. What i am looking for is a shared pref obj with a single key and 3 values.

Is it really possible? If yes, you can show me some direction.

Comment: I would use the split method of the String object...

Answer (score 0):

You can't store *three values* with a single key in the same [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) file, at least not on the abstraction level of the `SharedPreferences` object.

What you *can* do is store a JSON representation of the n 3-tuples (I think that's what you need). In other words, store a String which is made from a [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) of [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)s. This way, you need not care about separators, escaping and other such annoyances.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(getPathForUser(username, password) + PREF_RESOURCES_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);





public static String getPathForUser(String username, String password) {
        String sUsername = null;
        String sPassword = null;

        // sUsername
        if (username != null && username.trim().length() > 0) {
            sUsername = username.trim();
        } else {
            sUsername = "defaultUsername";
        }


        // sPassword
        if (password != null && password.trim().length() > 0) {
            sPassword = password.trim();
        } else {
            sPassword = "defaultPassword";
        }


        try {
            return URLEncoder.encode(sUsername, "UTF-8") + "__" + URLEncoder.encode(sPassword, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
```